# debian boot to recovery mode

Tags: linux, debian

I wrote a start up script that goes to an infinite loop but I forgot to start the process as a separate thread (&). Because the script runs as a daemon, it also gets stuck when shutting down.

Now when the system boots/shutsdown, it gets stuck...I can't exit it using Ctrl + C.

I also can't boot to recovery mode because I changed the default timeout on the grub bootloader to 0 (it used to be 5 seconds which allowed me to select the recovery mode etc).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Grub2 should still look for SHIFT to bring up the boot menu even if the timeout is set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from a USB stick, or a CD and fix the bootscripts. You could also try other means of killing the process, like C-\.